# The type org.hibernate.LockMode cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplat

Tags: spring

The type org.hibernate.LockMode cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDLsX.png)

Please someone help me with this

Have already specified the hibernate-core dependency in pom.xml file still getting that error